# OpenGL not displaying anything when gluLookAt called

Tags: c, opengl

I am working on a practice OpenGL program.  I am basically trying to display a pyramid.  I pasted the code I have so far bellow.  The issue I am having is that when I call gluLookAt my screen becomes completely black.  This does not make sense to me.  My pyramid has triangles with dimensions bounded within a box of size (1, 1, 1) and it is at the origin.  So therefore if I position the eye at something far away if (10, 10, 10) and look at (0, 0, 0) why do I not see the pyramid.  When I comment out gluLookAt I can see it clearly.

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct
{
    GLuint trifan;
    GLuint tribase;
    GLuint colors;
} b;

void display();
void init_buffer();
void check_errors();
void reshape(int w, int h);
void keyboard(unsigned char k, int x, int y);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
    glutCreateWindow("Pyramid");

    init_buffer();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);

    glutMainLoop();
}

void init_buffer()
{
    glGenBuffers(1, &(b.trifan));
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, b.trifan);

    GLfloat trifan[6][3] =
    {
        {0.0, 1.0, 0.0},
        {1.0, 0.0, 1.0},
        {-1.0, 0.0, 1.0},
        {-1.0, 0.0, -1.0},
        {1.0, 0.0, -1.0},
        {1.0, 0.0, 1.0}
    };

    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat) * 3 * 6, trifan, GL_STATIC_COPY);

    glGenBuffers(1, &b.colors);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, b.colors);

    GLfloat colors[6][3] = 
    {
            {1.0, 0.0, 0.0},
            {1.0, 0.0, 0.0},
            {1.0, 0.0, 0.0},
            {1.0, 0.0, 1.0},
            {0.5, 0.0, 1.0},
            {1.0, 0.0, 0.5},
    };
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat) * 3 * 6, colors, GL_STATIC_COPY);

    check_errors();
}

void reshape(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(60, (float)w / (float)h, 1.0, 100.0);
}

float angle = 0.0;
float zoom = 1.0;
void keyboard(unsigned char k, int x, int y)
{
    if(k == 'x')
    {
        angle += 10;
    }
    else if(k == 'y')
    {
        angle -= 10;
    }
    else if(k == 'w')
    {
        zoom += 0.1;
    }
    else if(k == 's')
    {
        zoom -= 0.1;
    }

    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glRotated(angle, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    gluLookAt(10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    {
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, b.trifan);
        glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, b.colors);
        glColorPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 6);
    }
    glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    check_errors();
    glFlush();
}

void check_errors()
{
    GLint err = glGetError();
    if(err != GL_NO_ERROR)
    {
        fputs((char*)gluErrorString(err), stderr);
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like the ordering of your vertex array is producing triangles with the wrong face facing the point you are looking from. Could you try to look at the point from the exact opposite side, as in (-10,-10,-10) or change the ordering of your vertices to match counter clock-wise orientation. Now looking at the center, if you can see your pyramid that also supports my point; that is you are inside the pyramid and the visible faces are inside looking.

Comment: Well I figured it out.  I forgot to register my reshape function with glut.